# ngx-mat-file-input mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am building an angular project with angular material. I have an error when using . Some of these mat form fields are working but some are not working.
I was trying to find out the solution but failed.
Let me attach my codes. Please let me know what kinds of code do you want to check else.

This is the HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Event Graphic</mat-label>
  <ngx-mat-file-input placeholder="Basic Input" formControlName="eventGraphicAttachment" ngDefaultControl>
  </ngx-mat-file-input>
  <mat-icon matSuffix>folder</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>

...
<mat-form-field class="black-list">
  <mat-list dense formControlName="eventBlackList" ngDefaultControl>
    <mat-list-item> User1 </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item> User2 </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item> User3 </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is package.json file content:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "confetti-js": "^0.0.18",
    "linkifyjs": "*",
    "magic-sdk": "^4.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^2.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/linkifyjs": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.36",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

And this is the error log:

```
ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
    at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.js:227)
    at MatFormField._validateControlChild (form-field.js:712)
    at MatFormField.ngAfterContentInit (form-field.js:519)
    at callHook (core.js:2573)
    at callHooks (core.js:2542)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2493)
    at refreshView (core.js:9507)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10637)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9263)
    at refreshView (core.js:9516)
```

Comment: stackblitz for the lazy?

Comment: Hi @garbear!
I'm sorry for can't share the project. It's not a public project...
Which part of the code do you want to check?

Comment: Where does `ngx-mat-file-input` comes from, it's likely not a `mat-form-field` as stated, or you're missing some imports.

Comment: I've installed node module ```"ngx-material-file-input": "^2.1.1"```
What should I import else?

Comment: Did you import the Module? `import { MaterialFileInputModule } from 'ngx-material-file-input';`

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you very much! Please add your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I added it. Thank you. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you did not import the module.

```
import { MaterialFileInputModule } from 'ngx-material-file-input';
```

Comment: Hi Lynx! Would you like to help me with one more problem that very similar to this problem?
I've added the next HTML code to my question.

Comment: The error log is same. I've already added MatListModule. What should I do?

Comment: Yes, I did. Added.

Comment: Did you import it from the right path? The structure was changed a couple of versions ago: `import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';`

Comment: Yes, This is my code ```import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';```
But it still shows several errors. :(

Comment: That's strange. I did the same on my side right now and I didn't get this error. Have you tried to restart your IDE and build the project again?

Comment: Restarted project, but it is same.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry but I have to leave for now. Please, add your package.json's content to let me check tomorrow. I'll get back to you within the next 10 hours.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time. I will update the question with package.json file.

Comment: I had a look at your package.json. I tried to set up a new project from scratch applying your setup. It does not work at all. Running `npm install` lead from one dependency error to the next. And I am pretty sure that this is the main problem for all the errors you currently get. Your dependencies are imballanced. -- My suggestion is to set up an entirely new angular project, copy paste the code but not the package.json and then adding all needed dependencies step by step. Otherwise you'll have a really hard time finding a balanced combination with your current `package.json`.